# How to identify records which have clusters or lumps in data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

I have a tableau table as follows:

[image: Tableau Table]

This data can be visualized as follows:

[image: Tableau Visual]

I'd like to flag cases that have lumps/clusters. This would flag items B, C and D because there are spikes only in certain weeks of the 13 weeks. Items A and E would not be flagged as they mostly have a 'flat' profile.

How can I create such a flag in Tableau or SQL to isolate this kind of a case?

What I have tried so far?:
I've tried a logic where for each item I calculate the MAX and MEDIAN. Items that need to be flagged will have a larger (MAX - MEDIAN) value than items that have a fairly 'flat' profile.

Please let me know if there's a better way to create this flag.

Thanks!

Comment: Anomaly detection is a broad subject.  Unless you have specific requirements this is too broad and quite possibly not appropriate for SQL.

Comment: You need to put some metrics around "lumps". E has lumps too.

Comment: If a product sold 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3 etc in consecutive weeks, is that a lump? It is a straight line on a graph, but the value changes a lot. I.E., are you looking for just changes in value, or only sharp changes (corners) in value?

Comment: In the future, please provide data in a table so we don't have to retype it to help you answer your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the other commenters that this question could be answered in many different ways and you might need a PhD in Stats to come up with an ideal answer.  However, given your basic requirements this might be the easiest/simplest solution you can implement.

[image: Answer]

Here is what I did to get here:

1. Create a parameter to define your "spike".  If it is going to always be a fixed number you can hardcode this in your formulas.  I called min "Min Spike Value".
2. Create a formula for the Median Values in each bucket.  `{fixed [Buckets]: MEDIAN([Values])}` . (A, B, ... E = "Buckets").  This gives you one value for each letter/bucket that you can compare against.
3. Create a formula to calculate the difference of each number against the median.  `abs(sum([Values])-sum([Median Values]))`.  We use the absolute value here because a spike can either be negative or positive (again, if you want to define it that way...).  I called this "Spike to Current Value abs difference"
4. Create a calculated field that evaluates to a boolean to see if the current value is above the threshold for a spike.  `[Spike to Current Value abs difference] > min([Min Spike Value])`

Setup your viz to use this boolean to highlight the spikes.  The beauty of the parameter is you can change the value for what a spike should be and it will highlight accordingly.  Above the value was 4, but if you change it to 8:

[image: Spike of 8]